# Drupal - Computed Fields - Taxonomy Term Weight?

Tags: drupal-6, taxonomy

With the Computed Fields module, can I get the taxonomy term weight from a specific vocabulary?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, VID_OF_MY_VOC, 'vid');
$weight = $terms[VID_OF_MY_VOC]->weight;
```

Comment: Im not getting any value returned. Ive copied your code and changed VID_OF_MY_VOC to my vocabulary ID. For the database storage ive tried using int, varchar and longtext and Ive played around with changing the data length. After doing this I edit and re-save nodes. Im looking at the field in a view and it stays empty. Thanks

Comment: Ive left the Display Format as it is, is that OK? Thanks